# QuickSort with Double Linked List

Tags: java, quicksort, doubly-linked-list

I am having trouble with my swap method in the Quick Sort program. I'm implementing it from a QuickSort method that sorts arrays. Here I take in a file with an integer on each line, it puts the number in a doubly linked list and then sorts the list and outputs to a new file. I need help with the swap method and what else I need to add or do to make it work properly. Any advise would help and examples are best. Thank you

```
    //swap A[pos1] and A[pos2]
   public static void swap(DList A, int pos1, int pos2){
      int temp = A.get(pos1); 
      A[pos1] = A[pos2]; 
      A[pos2] = temp; 
   }
```

My entire program for quicksort looks like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test_QuickSort{

   private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
   private static DList list = new DList(); 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      input = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

      while (input.hasNext())
      {
         String s = input.nextLine();
         DNode g = new DNode(Integer.parseInt(s));
         list.addLast(g);
      }
   //int[] A = {1,4,6,2};  

   QuickSort(list, 0, list.size()-1);

   //for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
   //    System.out.print(A[i] + " ");

   }

   public static void QuickSort(DList A, int left, int right){
      if(left >= right)
         return; 

      int pivot_index = partition(A, left, right); 
      QuickSort(A, left, pivot_index - 1);
      QuickSort(A, pivot_index + 1, right);
   }

   public static int partition(DList A, int left, int right){
      int pivot = A.get(right); 
      int index = left; 

      for(int i = left; i < right; i++){
         if(A.get(i) <= pivot){
            swap(A, index, i);
            index ++; 
         }
      }
      swap(A, index, right);
      return index; 
   }


    //swap A[pos1] and A[pos2]
   public static void swap(DList A, int pos1, int pos2){
      int temp = A.get(pos1); 
      A[pos1] = A[pos2]; 
      A[pos2] = temp; 
   }

}
```

My DList Method looks like this:

```
class DNode {
   protected int element;   // String element stored by a node
   protected DNode next, prev;  // Pointers to next and previous nodes

   public DNode(int e)
   {
      element = e;
      prev = null;
      next = null;
   }
   public DNode()
   {
      element = 0;
      next = null;
      prev = null;
   }
   public DNode(int e, DNode p, DNode n) {
      element = e;
      prev = p;
      next = n;
   }

   public int getElement() { 
      return element; }
   public DNode getPrev() { 
      return prev; }
   public DNode getNext() { 
      return next; }
   public void setElement(int newElem) { element = newElem; }
   public void setPrev(DNode newPrev) { prev = newPrev; }
   public void setNext(DNode newNext) { next = newNext; }
}

public class DList {
   protected int size;
   protected DNode header, trailer;
   public DList() { 
      size = 0;
      header = new DNode(0, null, null);    
      trailer = new DNode(0, header, null);
      header.setNext(trailer);
   }

   public int size() { 
      return size; }

   public boolean isEmpty() { 
      return (size == 0); }

   public DNode getFirst() throws IllegalStateException {
      if (isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("List is empty");
      return header.getNext();
   }

   public DNode getLast() throws IllegalStateException {
      if (isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("List is empty");
      return trailer.getPrev();
   }

   public DNode getPrev(DNode v) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      if (v == header) throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("Cannot move back past the header of the list");
      return v.getPrev();
   }

   public int get(int pos)
   {
      DNode current = new DNode();
      for(int i = 0; i <= pos && current != null; i++)
      {
         if(pos == 0){
            current = header;
         }
         else{
            current = current.next;
            break;
         }
      }
      return current.element;
   }

   public DNode getNext(DNode v) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      if (v == trailer) throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("Cannot move forward past the trailer of the list");
      return v.getNext();
   }

   public void addBefore(DNode v, DNode z) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      DNode u = getPrev(v); // may throw an IllegalArgumentException
      z.setPrev(u);
      z.setNext(v);
      v.setPrev(z);
      u.setNext(z);
      size++;
   }

   public void addAfter(DNode v, DNode z) {
      DNode w = getNext(v); // may throw an IllegalArgumentException
      z.setPrev(v);
      z.setNext(w);
      w.setPrev(z);
      v.setNext(z);
      size++;
   }

   public void addFirst(DNode v) {
      addAfter(header, v);
   }

   public void addLast(DNode v) {
      addBefore(trailer, v);
   }

   public boolean hasPrev(DNode v) { 
      return v != header; }

   public boolean hasNext(DNode v) { 
      return v != trailer; }

   public String toString() {
      String s = "[";
      DNode v = header.getNext();
      while (v != trailer) {
         s += v.getElement();
         v = v.getNext();
         if (v != trailer)
            s += ",";
      }
      s += "]";
      return s;
   }
}
```

Comment: Any help would be awesome?

Comment: Can you specify what isn't working as it should - what is the actual behavior and what behavior do you expect? "I need help with ..." isn't very precise. Edit: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, apparently you want to treat the instance of `DList` as an array, which isn't possible in Java. You probably want to implement a method to add a value at a certain index, e.g., `setValueAt(int index, int value)` and set the value as `A.setValueAt(pos1, A.getValueAt(pos2)`. I'll be happy to have a closer look if you make your question more specific.

Comment: @KuluLimpa I know that my get method isn't working properly because I get the same value no matter what I pass in. Also, my swap method is incorrect. I seeking help to freshen up my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are always retrieving the same element in `DList.get` is that you stop looping after the first iteration. Simply remove the `break`-statement, and the loop should work as intended.

```
public int get(int pos)
{
    DNode current = new DNode();
    for(int i = 0; i <= pos && current != null; i++)
    {
        if(pos == 0){
            current = header;
        }
        else{
            current = current.next;
            // break; <-- remove this
        }
    }
    return current.element;
}
```

Side note: You could get rid of the `if`-statement, if you would initialize `current` to `header`:

```
public int get(int pos)
{
    DNode current = header;
    for(int i = 1; i <= pos && current != null; i++)
    {
        current = current.next;
    }
    return current.element;
}
```

Now regarding your `swap`-method: As already stated, you try to treat the instance of `DList` as an array by trying to dereference an element using square-brackets. Instead, you should implement a method in `DList` that allows setting an element at a certain position. For example:

```
public void setAt(int pos, int value){
    DNode current = header;
    for(int i = 1; i <= pos && current != null; i++){
        current = current.next;
    }
    if(current != null)
        current.setElement(value);
    else
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

Now you can change your `swap`-method to:

```
public static void swap(DList a, int pos1, int pos2){
    int temp = a.get(pos1);
    a.setAt(pos1, a.get(pos2)); 
    a.setAt(pos2, temp); 
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes alot more sense. One question, when I am debugging my program, I noticed that my Double Linked List is initially creating 0,0 and adding on from there. so no matter what my list will have 0,0 included. I tried to set the intital value of the elements to null but got an error. Any advise? Thanks again

Comment: What error did you get? `NullPointerException`? Edit: Also, Java is initializing the value of reference types to `null` and the value of primitives to `0`, so if you have a field `element` and do not explicitly set it, then Java sets it to `0`.

Comment: if I do element = null; in my DNode() it says incompatiable type. I'm wanting to avoid the zeros and have the list of strickly integers that are passed in from the file. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: @ProgrammingHappy That's because `element` is of type `int`. Java distinguishes between primitive types (`int`, `double`, `float`, `long`, `byte`, `char`) and reference types (everything  else, including arrays - so an `int[]` is also a reference type). `null` is a special reference and can only be assigned to values of a reference type. Further note that you cannot dereference `null` and trying to do so will lead to a `NullPointerException`. Edit: You can initialize `element` to any (valid) number, e.g., `1`, if you want.